# Bulk Update in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, bulk

I have a table like this:

```
table_name     SQL_statement               id_value      result

employee       select ... where ..= :1    101           
customer       select ....where ..= :1    903
```

1. there will be about 6-8 different tables
2. the ID_VALUE is supplied as parameter to SQL_Statement
3. the SQL statement will always return a single row.
4. the result of "c" above should be stored in result column

I know I can use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, but that will create hard parsing in SGA.

What kind of BULK technique can be used here ?

Comment: a straightforward update statement for each table being updated would do the trick. How are the ids passed in? 1 at a time, or as the result of a select statement?

Comment: The objective is to pass ID_VALUE to SQL_STATEMENT using some kind of BULK operation.

Comment: Right, but how are you getting the id_values in the first place? Are they generated from within the database (eg. `select id_value from table_with_id_values where <some condition>`), or passed in an id at a time via a front end program, or something else?

Comment: `execute immediate` does not necessarily cause a hard parse if used with parameters

Comment: Agree with a_horse_with_no_name on hard parsing. It should be avoided to prevent SQL engine to pl-sql engine swap multiple times though.

Comment: Is `sql_statement` always the same for all rows where `table_name = 'employee'` ? If yes then one of the columns is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume that the statement always extracts a single value with a fixed alias, you can try the following.

**setup:**

```
create table yourTable(table_name varchar2(30), SQL_statement varchar2(100), id_value number, result number);
insert into yourTable
(
select 'employee', 'select :1 *2 as result from dual', 1,  null from dual union all           
select 'customer', 'select :1    as result from dual', 10, null from dual
);
```

Given the alias `result`, you can use a single update statement.

**update:**

```
update yourTable
set result = extractvalue(xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml(replace (SQL_statement, ':1', id_value))),'/ROWSET/ROW/RESULT')
```

**result:**

```
SQL> select *
2  from yourTable;

TABLE_NAME SQL_STATEMENT                              ID_VALUE     RESULT
---------- ---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
employee   select :1 *2 as result from dual                  1          2
customer   select :1    as result from dual                 10         10
```

Comment: @Boneist - the table is populated by another backend procedure. When a record in customer,employee etc is updated, a trigger populates this table with ID_VALUE which is the PK of the record being updated. So in above - 101 is PK of employee table and 903 is PK of customer table. Imagine this table having few million records.